# error on deploying EJB project on weblogic

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

```
Caused By: <openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:965591 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Table 'mock_test_db.Branch' doesn't exist {prepstmnt 32 SELECT t0.branch_id, t0.branch_desc, t0.branch_title FROM Branch t0} [code=1146, state=42S02]
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4207)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4171)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:88)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:64)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Table 'mock_test_db.Branch' doesn't exist {prepstmnt 32 SELECT t0.branch_id, t0.branch_desc, t0.branch_title FROM Branch t0} [code=1146, state=42S02]
        at org.apache.openjpa.util.Exceptions.replaceNestedThrowables(Exceptions.java:249)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException.writeObject(PersistenceException.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

this error I am getting while I am running my application , while some pages are working fine

Comment: "some pages are working fine".. Are they using the same table (mock_test_db.Branch)? Cause the error seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: nop they are not using the same table, and I am using JPA 1.0 and on server its JPA 2.0 will it makes a difference

Comment: I don't think the version of JPA matters. The error is very clear. The table isn't found.
The generated query is "select .. from Branch". The error, however, says "mock_test_db.Branch". I wonder if your unit tests that seem to be using "mock_test_db" username are actually included in the application you are deploying to WebLogic.